# $emit + $on / $broadcast + $on are not working in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need to call function in another controller in AngularJS. How it is possible? I used below code but it's not working.

### EmployeeCtrl

```
routerApp.controller('EmployeeController', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on("CallSearchtMethod", function (searchName) {
            $scope.parentmethod(searchName);
        });
        $scope.parentmethod = function (searchName) {
            console.log("data is" + searchName);
        }
    }
})
```

### NavCtrl

```
routerApp.controller('navCtrl', function ($scope,$rootScope ) {    
   $scope.searchFun = function (searchName) {
      $rootScope.$emit("CallSearchtMethod", searchName);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). What it does is that it allows you to create common functions that will be used in many places, which in this case are controllers.

Here is an example working code snippet that will guide you to do the Service.

```js
angular.module('starterByAR', ['starterByAR.controllers', 'starterByAR.services']);

angular.module('starterByAR.controllers', [])
.controller('mainOne', [
  '$scope', 'myService',
  function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.text = myService.commonFunction();
  }
])
.controller('mainTwo', [
  '$scope', 'myService',
  function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.text = myService.commonFunction();
  }
]);

angular.module('starterByAR.services', []).service('myService', function() {
  return {
    commonFunction: function(){
      return 'Some Text';
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Angular Starter</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="starterByAR">
  <div ng-controller="mainOne">
    Here is {{text}} from Controller 1
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="mainTwo">
    Here is {{text}} from Controller 2
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: make a working code snippet then I will edit from there.

Comment: Here I edited the answer to add a working code snippet as an example for you.